# Stepper Motor Supply Voltage

Tags: stepper-motor, ratings

My stepper rating is 0.33A per phase, 23.9Ω phase resistance and 29.8mH inductance/phase.

What voltage should I use to drive this motor so that it provides holding torque around 13.7Ncm (rated on motor)?

Comment: Three phase DC motor? Edit: Nevermind, it's a stepper motor, right? Two phase?

Answer (score 1):

You need the motor torque constant. It's sometimes called Kt and/or Ke. This parameter will let you relate current to torque. Then you can work backwards, starting with the torque you want, figure out what the current must be, and then ohms law will tell you what voltage will push that current.

Comment: This is is a fairly incomplete answer for the case of a *stepper* motor.  In a stepping motor, as the step rate increases the relationship between voltage and achieved current quickly becomes dominated not by the winding resistance, but rather by the winding inductance reacting to the commutation.

Comment: Ah, well and good, but otoh, when someone says "holding" torque, the "holding" part suggests a stopped condition.